# how to handle message in on_message mqtt paho if multiple message came at same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, mqtt, paho

```
return_message = ""

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):

    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe(topic)

def on_message(client, userdata, message):
   global return_message
   print("received data is :")  
   return_message = message.payload

client = mqtt.Client("user") 
client.on_connect=on_connect
client.on_message=on_message
client.connect(broker,port,60)
client.loop_start()
```

the return_message is a global variable. getting the message when there is only one message at a time. but i need to handle multiple messages at a time. how to handle this. if i declared return_message as an array then also i think there will be data loss . is there any better way to do this. i need to pass the return message value to other files also. how to do this

Comment: What action needs to be taken for each message? If you just want a threadsafe way to store them so another thread can process then consider using a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html).

Comment: thanks for your support . i will try with queue

Answer (score 1):

All messages are handled on the client network loop, this means only one message will be handled at once by default as only on instance of the `on_message` will run at once.

If you want to handle messages in parallel, maybe because processing that's a long time then you need to supply your own thread pool and pass message handling of to that pool.

Comment: thanks for your support . i have declared the return message as an array. then i have pushed the message.payload into that array, now i think i will get almost all data in it